# Display a field when it contains a value

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 6, I can use the following code in the *node.tpl.php* file.

```php
<?php if (content_format('field_occupation', $field_occupation[0]) != '') : ?>
  <?php foreach ($field_occupation as $occupation) { ?>
    <strong>Primary occupation: </strong>
    <?php print content_format('field_occupation', $occupation) ?>
  <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This doesn't seem to work in Drupal 7.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to d7 - just in time as d6 will soon become unsupported.
In D7, content_format is deprecated.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1054586

Check out this for how to render entity fields in d7: https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

You'll have to adapt your existing script to this new rendering method. It might be a good opportunity to clean up the presentation and readability of the script so that you'll be prepared for the inevitable migration to d8!